# Cant get laravel to save new user, send email & login & redirect

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send a Welcome email when a user registers, then log them in and redirect to their account page. I can get the email to send ok but the login/redirect wont work. The login/redirect does work if I remove the code for sending the email. I'm not sure why it wont let me do both. Here is my route:

```
Route::post('register', function()
{   
    $aRules = array(
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'membertype_id' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'brn' => 'required'
    );

$oValidator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$aRules);

if($oValidator->fails()){

    //return form with error messages and sticky data
    // return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($oValidator);
    return Redirect::back()->withInput();

}else{

    // Create User Account
    $aUserDetails = Input::all();
    $aUserDetails['photo'] = 'placeholder.png';

    if( Input::hasFile('photo')){

        $sNewName = Input::get('firstname').time().'.'.Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Input::file('photo')->move('img/users/', $sNewName);
        $aUserDetails['photo'] = $sNewName;
    }

    $aUserDetails['password'] = Hash::make($aUserDetails['password']);

    User::create($aUserDetails);

    // Send Welcome Email
    $emailcontent = array (
        'firstname' => $aUserDetails['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $aUserDetails['lastname'],
        'email' => $aUserDetails['email']

    );

    Mail::send('emails.registrationEmail', $emailcontent, function($message){
        $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Sudarshanaloka Registration Confirmation');
    });



    // Store message
    Session::flash('message', "<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Registation was Successful! &mdash; A confirmation email has also been sent.");

    // Login and redirect to user account page
    $login = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );


    if (Auth::attempt($login)) {
        return Redirect::to('users/'.Auth::user()->id);
    }

}
```

});

Comment: which mail driver are you using?

Comment: did you check your logs ? there might be an error throwing.

Comment: Just using the standard mail option. For some reason it started working last night so i think it may be an issue with the server.

Comment: I think you want `Auth::login($user)` instead of `if (Auth::attempt())` and also `$user = User::create()`